# Items de menú recorridos en Array!

Tags: php

Buenos días debo mostrar un menú que tiene 149 enlaces, cada enlace apunta a una página html, estos 149 enlaces los he colocado en un arreglo para poder hacer el recorrido y solo mostrar enlaces en grupos de 15, esto lo he hecho con una variable $total = count($menu) y lo he dividido entre la variable $total_menu, para que me muestre solo los primeros 15 enlaces. Luego justo en la mitad de los elementos <a href""> de Anterior y Siguiente, he colocado una línea para imprimir el resultado del recorrido del array con su respectivo enlace o página, el problema que tengo es que me imprime indefinidamente el texto del enlace "Página" y en los enlaces me muestra un error que dice Notice: Array to String Conversion in line 180 justo donde estoy imprimiendo el los enlaces.

```
$menu = array('<a href="881901b97e54958e1199cc3c3f2c0986-2.html" target="contents" >Page 1</a><br/>'');
.......Etc..
$total = count($menu);
//echo $menu['148'];

$total_menu = 10;
$resultado = $total / $total_menu;
$resultado = ceil($resultado);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
   <section class="paginacion">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="menu1.php?pagina=<?php echo    $_GET['pagina']-1 ?>">Anterior</a>
           </li>
           <?php /*
           <?php for ($i=0;$i<$resultado;$i++): ?>
           */
           ?>
           <?php $i=0; 
while ($i<=$total) {
   

           ?>
           <li>
               <a href="menu1.php?pagina=<?php echo [$i]?>">Página</a>
               <?php
               }
               ?>
               <?php /*
               <a href="menu1.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1 ?>" target="contents" ><?php echo $i+1 ?></a>
</li>
<?php endfor ?>*/?>

<li>
   <a href="menu1.php?pagina=<?php echo    $_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">Siguiente.</a>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no eran necesarias 150 iguales para mostrar tu error... con un comentario que dijera que tu array tenia 150 lineas igual era suficiente... ahora... el tag que buscabas no seria php? porque tu problema no es html... y luego.. cual es la linea 180 que es donde ocurre el error?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, ya he corregido la publicación. Espero me comprendas.

Comment: mejor.. y cual es la linea 180?

Comment: El error te dice que estas intentando tratar un array como si fuese un string. Aparte luego en el <a> imprimes [$i], que no tiene ningún sentido. Para ver la posición de  un array es $array[$i], fíjate también que  estas abriendo un while y no lo cierras.

Comment: Hola esta es la línea donde está el error: dentro de un While quiero mostrar los enlaces de 1 a 15 y a si sucesivamente: <a href="menu1.php?pagina=<?php echo [$i]?>">Página</a>